# How to use Use F function keys as Control Strip Default Set in MBP Touch Bar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

In the MBP touch bar, I have selected the use of F function key rows for the touch bar. Touchbar always shows up as F1, F2...F12. I attained many shortcut combinations to them and use them in many places including IDEs. I would like to use them as standalone to function as a Control strip default as well.

For instance(MVP);

F1  Reduce the screen's brightness

F2  Increase the screen's brightness

F3  Activates Expose view, which shows you every app that's running

...

F10 Mute

F11 Reduces volume

F12 Increases volume

I know that pressing fn changes them to Control Strip temporarily, but that is not my aim. I would like to use directly F keys to perform those functions.
How to assign those functions to these F keys?

This question can also be asked in some other way:
How to assign Control Strip Default Set to an external keyboard?

Comment: What have you [looked into so far](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Sure, why not? :)

Comment: So, what did your research show so far? What options have you looked into? What websearches did you do? It's not a problem if you didn't find anything useful, but then at least people know what you've tried already and what didn't work. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Well, that is why I am asking :D

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but what google search did you do? What did you find? It is hard to suggest something without knowing what you have tried already.

Comment: I have seen some additional packages to do that. But I am looking for some native solutions within MacOS like assigning F2 to 'Show Notification Center' in keyboard shortcuts in Preferences.

Comment: For instance here, it recommends a third-party shortcut manager: (https://superuser.com/questions/319396/how-do-i-control-the-volume-with-a-non-mac-keyboard)

Comment: Ok, good to [edit] into your question what you want, already saw, and don't want. So far it seems you want the F-keys act as F-keys, but without pressing the Fn key you want them also to act to e.g. show the notification center, right? So how does the F-key know when it needs to act as an F-key and when to act as to do an action?

Comment: Nope, the F key can already act for the Notification center, I want Control Strip as I have explained in the question. Thank for you your help, I believe the question is clear and understandable.

Comment: Alright, with such a clear question you shouldn't have any problem in getting an answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.6.1, so ymmv.

In the Keyboard preferences there is a dropdown for "Touch Bar shows", which appears that you can change to what you are looking for.

[image: Keyboard preferences with "Touch Bar shows" dropdown open and "F1, F2, etc. Keys" selected]

Comment: That is not what I am asking. That is my setting already (use F1,F2, etc. Keys). The problem is when you select to use F1, F2, keys; they do not work for control strip things (like opening brightness or increasing volume). I want them to do both.